# Switch to a different version of ruby using homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, homebrew

I migrated my MacBook using Migration Assistant. I have two rails apps I was working on my previous laptop and now when I try working on those apps on my new laptop one them works properly(Restaurant App) and in the other(Quiz App) when I try to turn on the server I get this

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1
```

Both the apps have ruby version 2.5.1. What could be the possible reason the I am able to run the server on one app(Restaurant App) and not the other(Quiz App).

I tried running the command below to switch the ruby version to 2.5.1

```
brew unlink ruby@2.2.3 && brew link --force --overwrite ruby@2.5.1
```

but I get an error

```
No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@2.2.3
```

Please help me figure out this problem.

Comment: Are you certain Ruby 2.5.1 is listed on both Gemfiles? Try deleting the Gemfile.lock file on the app that's not starting and doing a bundle install and try again.

Comment: ruby '2.5.1' I have this in my gemfile.

Comment: Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1 this is what I get when I run bundle install

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.5.1`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: @anothermh I already have ruby 2.5.1 installed and it works on my other app. How to switch ruby version for this app.

Comment: You're not hearing me. Don't use brew to install Ruby. Use a Ruby manager to install Ruby.

Comment: @anothermh Should I first uninstall the existing ruby version which I install using brew?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally you're better off using a ruby version manager. The two major ones being RVM (https://rvm.io/) and rbenv

I'm personally a big fan of rbenv and its use of shims (I have less trouble when using bundler and switching xcode versions via xcversion personally) https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

```
brew install rbenv 
rbenv install 2.5.1
rbenv use 2.5.1
```

optionally you can use a .ruby-version file in your project root to ensure you don't have an issue again. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version

```
# in your project root
echo '2.5.1' > .ruby-version
```

In this way you can easily select whichever version you'd like to use for your application, just by starting it in the project root.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer for it save my day. However, `use` command is no longer available in rbenv, so maybe we can change it to `rbenv global RUBY_INSTALLED_VERSION`.

Comment: there is no command this ```rbenv use```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the instructions on MacOS 14.0. 2.5.1 doesn't exist anymore. 2.7.0 doesn't build. I installed 2.7.8, with the commands

brew install rbenv
rbenv install 2.7.8
rbenv global 2.7.8

This displays a warning

WARNING: ruby-2.7.8 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

so you might want to try out a later version. (At the moment I'm just following instructions at  https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native to install react-native and fix all the problems that come up).