# rbenv and managing ruby versions not working. Need 2.5.1

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv

I'm on Mac OS 10.14.6 (Mojave).

I'm trying to switch to ruby version 2.5.1 with rbenv, but i'm getting no errors or any luck changing... I also tried [Switch to a different version of ruby using homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064592/switch-to-a-different-version-of-ruby-using-homebrew), but had no luck.

```
jj:project me$ rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.2
jj:project me$ brew -v
Homebrew 2.2.14
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision ffa73; last commit 2020-05-03)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision f3b530; last commit 2020-05-03)
jj:project me$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
jj:project me$ rbenv install 2.5.1
jj:project me$ rbenv local 2.5.1
rbenv: version `2.5.1' not installed
jj:project me$ rbenv install -l
...
2.4.10
2.5.0-dev
2.5.0-preview1
2.5.0-rc1
2.5.0
2.5.1
2.5.2
...
```

I've tried `rbenv uninstall 2.5.1` and it says `rbenv: version`2.5.1' not installed`. I updated brew and ruby-build too. Xcode looks fine... not sure what else to try...

Seems i can even run `rbenv install 99` and got no errors. Same with `rbenv install gibberish` 
Eff...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try reinstalling `rbenv`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `eval "$(rbenv init -)”` to ~/.bashrc ?

If you didn’t, you can try add this and exec `source ~/.bashrc`.